# I want to write objects for user and role using hibernate and spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new in hibernate and don't know am I correct while writing objects.

I want a relationship which is bidirectional for users and roles.

While getting user from controller I am not getting correct object.

User has multiple roles and role has a user. My objects are:

```
package com.dineshonjava.sdjpa.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class UserRole  implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4515711679485233980L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_role_id",
    unique = true)
private Integer userRoleId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_role_id")},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="username")})  
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "role", length = 45)
private String role;

/**
 * @param role
 */
public UserRole() {
}

/**
 * @param userRoleId
 * @param role
 */
public UserRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public UserRole(User user, String role) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
}

public Integer getUserRoleId() {
    return this.userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

And user is:

```
package com.dineshonjava.sdjpa.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7500832548478837146L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true,
         length = 45)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password",
             length = 60)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
//  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="username")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_role_id")})
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public User(String username, String password,
        boolean enabled, Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
        return this.userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

}
```

Saving object like:

UserRole role = new UserRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        roleDAO.save(role);

```
User user = new User("username", "password", true, new HashSet<UserRole>(Arrays.asList(role)));

userDAO.save(user);
```

Service is:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl  extends HibernateSessionFactroyBase implements UserService{

    public void save(User user){
        getSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User find(String username) {
        return getSession().get(User.class, username);
    }

}
```

Session factory:

```
@Transactional
public class HibernateSessionFactroyBase {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   }
}
```

Application class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJpaSpringDataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJpaSpringDataApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public User get(@RequestParam(name = "id") String id) {

    User user = userRepository.find(id);
    return user;
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dineshonjava.sdjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootJPASpringData</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootJPASpringData</name>
    <description>SpringBootJPASpringData project for Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA implementation</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Property file:

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database 
# connection. In this example we have "dojsb" as database name and 
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

# Naming strategy
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

Comment: Separating code from question text a bit better.

Comment: You're expecting to get a `User` and you're getting ... what?